# How to save a permissions group

Tags: permissions, site-template

Is it possible to save an entire Permissions group as a template with all the users within the group to bring over to another site?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to copy People and group from one site to another](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/35288/how-to-copy-people-and-group-from-one-site-to-another)

and

http://praveenbattula.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/copy-users-from-one-sharepoint-group-to.html

and

[Export people and groups from one sharepoint site to another](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37804/export-people-and-groups-from-one-sharepoint-site-to-another)

and

http://discoverlars.wordpress.com/2012/05/01/easy-way-to-move-copy-or-add-bulk-multiple-accounts-in-sharepoint-groups/

hope it helps :)